# Placing .gitignore abover web root?

Tags: .gitignore

I wonder where should I place my .gitignore file when the EE system folder is above the root and I need to track those files.

This is my .gitignore at the moment:

```
# Globals and OS junk files
[Tt]humbs.db
.DS_Store
*.DS_Store
cgi-bin/
error_log

# Subversion files
.svn

# Master Config
config/config.local.php

# Images and Media
sized/
thumbs/
_thumbs/
made/
remote/
public_html/media/**/*
!public_html/media/**/*.gitkeep

# Caches
system/expressionengine/cache/**/*
system/expressionengine/cache/eedt/**/*
!system/expressionengine/cache/**/index.html
!system/expressionengine/cache/**/*.gitkeep
!system/expressionengine/cache/**/current_version
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Above the webroot in this case.

Comment: In that case, do I need to add rules like ignoring "public_ftp" folder, for instance?

Comment: that depends I guess. I wouldn't have thought you'd have that directory locally - unless you've dumped your production environment into your local machine. If you've done that then yes. Your setup is pretty identical to ours.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you know this, but you shouldn't set up your production sites like that. Ideally it should be:

```
.git
.gitignore
system/
third_party/
templates/
webroot/
```

etc.

You don't want any expressionengine files, addon files, or .git files to be accessible via webroot, or even set up some system to make them unavailable - the easiest and safest is just to keep them outside the webroot.

Comment: Even with this approach, the question is still valid for gitignore files because you may have more than one. Gitignore files further down the hierarchy override those that are higher up. Granted, he mentioned one gitignore file for ExpressionEngine, but there still may be other gitignore files for other items in the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't want my deployment method to dictate my placement of Git related files. I would rather my deployment process "clean" my environment and perhaps as a back-up, configure the web server to not serve Git related files. For example, here are some suggestions for Apache configurations in another question.

https://serverfault.com/questions/128069/how-do-i-prevent-apache-from-serving-the-git-directory